# Need Help Fixing Reoccurring Problem Error Message: 'Thread 1: "String does not represent a valid UUID"'

Tags: swift, bluetooth, uuid

I am having problems with getting a bluetooth capability function running on my xcode project. It seems that I keep running into the same errer everytime I try to fix this. I don't know what routes I can take to work around this error but any input would be great in helping me fix this problem. I am currently using IOS 16.6 on my device I am running this on and even before the project is ran, the app crashes. If you are able to have a look into fixing this for me that would be great. I have linked the code below.
Cheers

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreBluetooth

struct BluetoothPage: View {
    @ObservedObject private var bluetoothService: BluetoothService

    init() {
        let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: "8CD7C6A6-A23C-F514-6FDC-A45B978F64A1")
        bluetoothService = BluetoothService(serviceUUID: serviceUUID)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Discovered Devices")
                .font(.title)
                .padding()

            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    ForEach(bluetoothService.discoveredDevices, id: \.self) { deviceName in
                        Text(deviceName.isEmpty ? "Unnamed Device" : deviceName)
                            .padding()
                    }
                }
            }

            Button(action: {
                bluetoothService.scanForDevices()
            }) {
                Text("Scan for Devices")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

class BluetoothService: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var discoveredDevices: [String] = []
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    private var peripheral: CBPeripheral!
    private let serviceUUID: CBUUID

    init(serviceUUID: CBUUID) {
        self.serviceUUID = serviceUUID
        super.init()

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            scanForDevices()
        }
    }

    func scanForDevices() {
        centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [serviceUUID], options: nil)
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                        advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        // Filter and connect to the desired peripheral
        if peripheral.name == "Arduino" {
            self.peripheral = peripheral
            centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil) // Discover all services
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }

        for service in services {
            if service.uuid == CBUUID(string: "8CD7C6A6-A23C-F514-6FDC-A45B978F64A1") {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service) // Discover all characteristics
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            if characteristic.uuid == CBUUID(string: "8CD7C6A6-A23C-F514-6FDC-A45B978F64A1") {
                peripheral.discoverDescriptors(for: characteristic) // Discover descriptors
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        guard let descriptors = characteristic.descriptors else { return }

        for descriptor in descriptors {
            if descriptor.uuid == CBUUID(string: "2901") {
                peripheral.readValue(for: descriptor) // Read(descriptor)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
        guard let value = descriptor.value as? Data else { return }

        // Process the descriptor value
        if let forceValue = String(data: value, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Force Value: \(forceValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding in UUID's to the code to no pervail.

Comment: "2901" isn't a valid UUID. What is your intention of checking `if descriptor.uuid == CBUUID(string: "2901")`?

Comment: Please only post relevant code.